# Make a vector from a function with elseif

Tags: r, if-statement

I want to use a vector `(Temp<-(-6:20))` as an input and in return get a vector `(y)`. It does not work, I just get the Warning message:

```
"In if (Temp <= -5) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used"
```

The function:

```
my_funct <- function(Temp){
  if(Temp<= -5){y<- 100} else if(Temp<=5){y<-Temp^2} else {y<-Temp}
  y
}
```

Note: the function is simplified from my original one

Comment: Maybe add `R` tag? What language is this?

Comment: Thanks, I am new to this. I have now added the tag r, tried to edit the title as well but didn`t manage :(

Comment: Look into the function `ifelse()`. It's meant to take vectors instead of single values.

Comment: `ifelse(Temp <= -5, 100, ifelse(Temp<=5, Temp^2, Temp))`